# docker-compose can't connect to adjacent service via service name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cypress, docker-network

I have this docker-compose.yml that basically builds my project for e2e test.  It's composed of a postgres db, a backend Node app, a frontend Node app, and a spec app which runs the e2e test using cypress.
      version: '3'

```
  services:
    database:
      image: 'postgres'
    backend:
      build: ./backend
      command: /bin/bash -c "sleep 3; yarn backpack dev"
      depends_on:
        - database
    frontend:
      build: ./frontend
      command: /bin/bash -c "sleep 15; yarn nuxt"
      depends_on:
        - backend
    spec:
      build:
        context: ./frontend
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.e2e
      command: /bin/bash -c "sleep 30; yarn cypress run"
      depends_on:
        - frontend
        - backend
```

The Dockerfiles are just simple Dockerfiles that based off node:8 which copies the project files and run `yarn install`.  In the spec Dockerfile, I pass `http://frontend:3000` as FRONTEND_URL.

But this setup fails at the `spec` command when my cypress runner can't connect to `frontend` with error:

```
  spec_1      |   > Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.4:3000
```

As you can see, it resolves the hostname `frontend` to the IP correctly, but it's not able to connect. I'm scratching my head over why can't I connect to the frontend with the service name. If I switch the command on `spec` to do `sleep 30; ping frontend`, it's successfully pinging the container. I've tried deleting and let docker-compose recreate the network, I've tried specifying `expose` and `links` to the services respectively. All to no success.

I've set up a sample repo here if you wanna try replicating the issue:
https://github.com/afifsohaili/demo-dockercompose-network

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application is listening on loopback:

```
$ docker run --rm --net container:demo-dockercompose-network_frontend_1 nicolaka/netshoot ss -lnt                                                               
State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.11:35233                    *:*
LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.1:3000                     *:*
```

From outside of the container, you cannot connect to ports that are only listening on loopback (`127.0.0.1`). You need to reconfigure your application to listen on all interfaces (`0.0.0.0`).

For your app, in the package.json, you can add (according to the [nuxt faq](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/)):

```
  "config": {
    "nuxt": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": "3000"
    }
  },
```

Then you should see:

```
$ docker run --rm --net container:demo-dockercompose-network_frontend_1 nicolaka/netshoot ss -lnt
State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128          *:3000                     *:*
LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.11:39195                    *:*
```

And instead of an unreachable error, you'll now get a 500:

```
...
frontend_1  |   response: undefined,        
frontend_1  |   statusCode: 500,                                                                 
frontend_1  |   name: 'NuxtServerError' }
...
spec_1      | The response we received from your web server was:
spec_1      |                                                                                     
spec_1      |   > 500: Server Error
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. p.s. For the rest of you - I've also updated the demo github repo with the updated working solution. Just diff with the previous commit to see what I did.